# React native - Paginated SectionList inside ScrollView

Tags: react-native, pagination, react-native-flatlist, react-native-scrollview

My screen layout is `SectionList` inside a `View` and on `onEndReached` I am calling an API to get paginated data successfully (LoadMore behaviour).

As, `SectionList` is covering only 40% part of screen, I tried adding `ScrollView` so that complete screen becomes scrollable.

**Problem:** When the screen loads it fetches the initial paginated data. After rendering the UI, `onEndReached` event gets fired which in-turn calls api to get load more data again. This runs in loop until the complete data is fetched.

Has anyone faced the same issue. Any solution how to stop that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of adding a `SectionList` inside `ScrollView`, What you can do is by adding your above view (i.e. your other 60% area) as header of the `SectionList`. This way your entire screen will be treated as `SectionList`, and `onEndReached` will only gets called when user performs scroll.

Comment: Worked. Thanks !!